# How to get a string from TextIO in sml/ml?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

I'm trying to read text from a file in SML.  Eventually, I want a list of individual words; however, I'm struggling at how to convert between a `TextIO.elem` to a `string`.  For example, if I write the following code it returns a `TextIO.elem` but I don't know how to convert it to a string so that I can concat it with another string

`TextIO.input1 inStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextIO.elem` is just a synonym for `char`, so you can use the `str` function to convert it to a string. But as I replied to elsewhere, I suggest using `TextIO.inputAll` to get a string right away.

Here is a function that takes an instream and delivers all (remaining) words in it:

```
val words = String.tokens Char.isSpace o TextIO.inputAll
```

The type of this function is `TextIO.instream -> string list`.